# Does wifi and bluetooth scanning work when the location setting is turned off?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, gps, geolocation, location-services

[image]I have the "bluetooth and wifi scanning" setting listed under "location" section of my phone settings. That makes me think that only when an app is requesting geolocation is it able to use the feature called "wifi and Bluetooth scanning". Or am I wrong? Are apps constantly abusing this feature even if they don't have the geolocation permission or if the geolocation access is disabled altogether with a settings toogle?

Comment: See this [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248564/how-does-precise-and-approximate-location-work-on-android-12#comment334137_248564) and others below that//Wifi scanning does improve your [location accuracy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/15010/131553) //IMO Bluetooth doesn't//In any case you can [turn them off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBbCK.png) and still use GPS//Essentially, both scans are to connect to different networks /devices faster